# Evidence for differences in resilience between generations

Tags: personality, measurement

There is a lot of talk of younger generations being "softer" but is there any evidence for differences in resilience or hardiness between generations?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  "Softer" is not exactly a technical term in psychology...  Can you clarify what you mean by this?  Also, check out: [Are millenials more risk-averse than prior generations were (at the same age)?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20155/7001)

Comment: I mean merasurable differences in resilience or hardiness or grit